# How can I do this sql filter results

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have an website there are 5 categories, i only want to show the 1-4 category only in the new posts..how can I edit the code to do this job? thanks

Here is my code, and I do that in my sql by using following code:

```
 SELECT * FROM `ff_se` WHERE Wid in ('1','2','3','4')"
```

but i dont know how to do that in php code. following is my part of php code:

```
$this->TableSe = 'ff_se';
    $this->TableSeWord = 'ff_se_word';
    $this->TableSeSupport = 'ff_se_support';
    $this->TableSePost = 'ff_se_post';
    $this->TableSePostTableId = 'ff_se_post_tableid';

public function GetAjaxList($Get){
    $Results = array();
    $Get = $this->StrToGBK($Get);
    $Page = $Get['page'] ? intval($Get['page']):0;

    $Where = '';
    $Order = 'S.updateline';
    if($Get['type'] == 'New'){
        $Order = 'S.dateline';
    }else if($Get['type'] == 'Hot'){
        $Order = 'S.updateline';
        if($this->Config['PluginVar']['ListHotVal']){
            $Where .= ' and (S.support_count >= '.$this->Config['PluginVar']['ListHotVal'].' OR S.comment_count >= '.$this->Config['PluginVar']['ListHotVal'].')';
        }
        if($this->Config['PluginVar']['ListHotDataline']){
            $Where .= ' and S.dateline >= '.strtotime("-".$this->Config['PluginVar']['ListHotDataline']." hours",time());   
        }
    }else if($Get['type'] == 'Nearby'){//
        $Order = 'S.updateline';
        if($Get['lng'] && $Get['lat']){
            $SquarePoint = $this->GetReturnSquarePoint($Get['lng'],$Get['lat'],$this->Config['PluginVar']['Distance']);
            $Where .= ' and S.lat <> 0 and S.lat > '.$SquarePoint['right-bottom']['lat'].' and S.lat < '.$SquarePoint['left-top']['lat'].' and S.lng > '.$SquarePoint['left-top']['lng'].' and S.lng < '.$SquarePoint['right-bottom']['lng'];
        }else{
            return $Results;
        }
    }

    if($_GET['wid']){
        $Where .= ' and S.wid = '.intval($_GET['wid']);
    }
    $Where .= ' and S.display = 1 and S.fast_add_display = 1';
    $Where = preg_replace('/and/','where',$Where,1);

    $this->Config['PluginVar']['ListNum'] = $this->Config['PluginVar']['ListNum'] ? $this->Config['PluginVar']['ListNum'] : 10;
    $Limit = 'LIMIT '.($Page * $this->Config['PluginVar']['ListNum']).','.$this->Config['PluginVar']['ListNum'];

    $FetchSql = 'SELECT W.title as Ttitle,S.* FROM '.DB::table($this->Tablese).' S LEFT JOIN '.DB::table($this->TableSeWord).' W on W.id = S.wid '.$Where .' order by topdateline > '.time().' desc,'.$Order.' desc,S.dateline desc '.$Limit;
    $Results = $this->ListFormat(DB::fetch_all($FetchSql));
    return $Results;
}
```

Comment: _..i dont know how to do that in php code..._ Why doing this in both? You said mysql is working ... why php?

Comment: @B001ᛦ he wants to do it using PHP. the same thing he has done using MySQL. He wants to know where he can use the same query in his PHP code and replace the old query.

Comment: yes...i wants to do it using PHP. the same thing he has done using MySQL. I wants to know where he can use the same query in his PHP code and replace the old query

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try and understand the code first before you modify it ... but anyway:

You would only need to append the condition to the where clause generated in the PHP code.
You could do that by adding THE LINE MARKED "THIS LINE IS NEW" after this line:

```
$Where = '';
```

And this is the relevant part of the code:

```
$Where = '';
$Order = 'S.updateline';
if($Get['type'] == 'New'){
    $Where .= ' and S.wid in (1,2,3,4)'; //THIS LINE IS NEW
    $Order = 'S.dateline';
}else .......
```

As you can see any redundant initial "and"s are replaced with "where" here:

```
$Where = preg_replace('/and/','where',$Where,1);
```

so this should work - assuming that `$Get['type'] == 'New'` means that this is a new post which I can only guess.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..after your edition, it is not work, it just show blank page.

Comment: Have you checked for syntax or SQL errors? The data type of wid is probably integer but I don't know. So you might want to change the code again. I have updated the NEW LINE above. You also might want to post the entire code AFTER making the change. I could take a look at that too.

Comment: i tested add these works: and S.wid = 1 or S.wid = 2 or S.wid = 3

Comment: you have to be very careful with this because the WHERE clause has multiple ANDs that are generated. If you are not using brackets like in: and (S.wid = 1 or S.wid = 2 or S.wid = 3 or S.wid = 4) you might be in trouble.

Comment: and change to these, it works well>> $Where .= ' and S.wid = 1 or S.wid = 2 or S.wid = 3 or S.wid = 4'; //THIS LINE IS NEW

Comment: it seems that now it works well: $Where .= ' and S.wid in (1,2,3,4)';

Comment: these 2 changes works too. which one I should use now? thanks

Comment: I would use $Where .= ' and S.wid in (1,2,3,4)'; because it is the most concise and it works!

Comment: thanks so much for your help, it works now. but it seems become another problem..I would like to private chat with rf1234 , but it told me that i have only 1 reputation. any method can chat with you? i have another issue wanna ask you. thanks so much !!!!

Comment: @Leung: If my answer works for you could you accept it please.

Comment: ok, write a comment and I can see what I can do. We can delete the comments later if you like.

Comment: Not that I would know about. Why don't you post a new question?

Comment: after change the code. there is no No.5 category of win in the index , because it only show (1,2,3,4). but when I directly go to the No.5 category with his own link..it show blank page.. how to fix it?? it seems that it along with the previous setting.

Comment: No.5 category own link is: xxx.com/xxx&wid=5

Comment: Sorry, @Leung. It is impossible to tell beause it would require far more detail about your application which I don't have. How can you "directly go to the No. 5 category" if it is not displayed by limiting the selection to categories 1 - 4?? This doesn't really make sense for me, sorry. You see: I cannot help you remotely with stuff like this without knowing all the details of your application! Please try to thoroughly understand your application and you should find the problem, I am sure.

Comment: Would you kindly accept this answer please 
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235